# replicate mysql db from slave server to another slave server

Tags: mysql, database-replication

Can anybody help to set replication from MySQL db from slave server (which is already getting data from a Master server)
I want to replicate db of this slave server to another server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mr @Mirza: This link may help u http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication-multi-master.html

Comment: Note that there is a high likeliness that the slave data does not match the master; any update from one slave to another needs to take this into account. You also do not get the master info needed to go with the data received from the slave. In essence, you are only getting relatively recent data and need to fix the end result by checking against the master.

Answer (score 1):

The first port of call would be the MySQL documentation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Spefic to your query the following is also worth reading

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-existingdata.html